# Can't set state data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react programming. It might be silly mistake but, i can't access state data in my smart component.

Following is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = { 
            resData: [], 
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://someurl.com/something`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => { alert(result.data[0].title); this.setState({ resData: result.data }));

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <ErrorBoundary>
                    <Content data={ this.state.resData } />
                </ErrorBoundary>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }

export default App;
```

If i alert data in following then it was there.

```
.then(result => { alert(result.data[0].title) setState({ resData: result.data })); //Here i can see my data.
```

I want to pass this state data to my component. But, there are no data.

```
<Content data={ this.state.resData } />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well `.then(result => setState({ resData: result.data }));` only happens when the HTTP request completes; the `alert()` call happens long before then.

Comment: in your smart component should call **this.props.data.length ? this.props.data[0].title**

Comment: I think the problem is: inside then, this is not the Component scope but the lambda function. Check your console, if it says that this or seState is undefined.

Comment: @cutiko No there is nothing like undefined for this or setState

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try now:
You need to use this keyword with setState()

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
  this.state = {
    resData: [],
  } 
}

componentDidMount() {
fetch(`http://someurl.com/something`)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    this.setState({ resData: result.data })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    alert("Username password do not match")
  })
}



render() {
const { resData } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    {resData &&
      <Header />
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Content data={resData} />
      </ErrorBoundary>
      <Footer />
        }
  </div>
 );
}

export default App;

Check it now
```

Comment: Sorry, It did nothing.

Comment: alert(this.state.resData) will still give you [ ] as you are logging a value gathered asyncronously, so at the moment of the alert that field is not populated. Using this.setState will work and populate your state.

If you want to directly use setState you have to deconstruct setState from `this` like `const { setState } = this`;

Comment: just do a `console.log(this.state.resData)` in the first line inside `render()`, you should see a `undefined` followed by your actual data

Comment: check here :  .then(result => this.setState({ resData: result.data }));

Comment: @ShivaKumarN I tried to console.log(this.state.resData) in first line of render. It shows [object Object]. How can i pass that data to component?

Comment: I don't want to alert the data. I want to pass that data to component. Here. <Content data={ this.state.resData } /> which shows nothing

Comment: can you check it now.

Comment: No actually. It didn't load data still

Answer (score 0):

The alert is running before the setState is finishing, try running the alert as a callback to setState:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`http://someurl.com/something`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => this.setState({ resData: result.data }), () => {
          alert(this.state.resData);
        });
    }
```

Comment: My purpose is not to alert data. I want to pass in component.

Comment: I understand thats your purpose, but if the data is logging it should go to the component just fine, if you run the alert as a callback to setState do you get back data?

Comment: pass the data like this to the new component <ComponentName data={this.state.resData}/> and in new component use this.props.data

Answer (score 0):

try this it might help

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';

        class App extends Component {
            constructor() {
                super();

                this.state = { 
                    resData: [], 
                }
            }

            componentDidMount() {
    var that = this;
                fetch(`http://someurl.com/something`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => { alert(result.data[0].title); that.setState({ resData: result.data }));

    alert(that.state.resData);
            }

            render() {
var that = this;
                return (
                    <div>
                        <Header />
                        <ErrorBoundary>
                            <Content data={ that.state.resData } />
                        </ErrorBoundary>
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                );
            }

        export default App;
```